# Codeigniter 301 redirection index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, redirect

I want to do 301 redirection after removing index.php in codeigniter.

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|img|js|plugins|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

After this I added

```
RewriteRule /index.php?page=9-someting&txt=12 /page/1/someting#2/other [R=301,L]
```

but redirection does not work any help?

EDIT:

/index.php?page=9-someting&txt=12 the old site that was not written in CodeIgniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your second, more special rule before the usual CI's nice url's catch-all-and-send-to-index rule. You might also want to add `NE` (as no encode) because the hashmark (`#`) will be encoded otherwise.

So something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# rewrite old site url, has L so processig will stop here for matching requests.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=9-someting&txt=12$
RewriteRule index.php /page/1/someting#2/other [R=301,L,NE]


# request that fall trouhg will be sent to CI's front controller (if they are not images, css....)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|img|js|plugins|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: does not work, if I put anything except index.php everything is work normally.

Comment: Sorry, i just realized that you are trying to match query string parameters in the `RewriteRule` line. That's not gonna work there, you will have to use a `RewriteCond` since `RewriteRules` matches request's url-path.

Comment: This works, but is it possible that after the url redirection is not:
mysite.com/page/1/someting#2/other?index.php?page=9-someting&txt=12

Comment: That should not happen, these rewrites are not supposed to be relative on the current URL, I'm not sure what's happening there.

Comment: Chrome says 'This webpage has a redirect loop'?

Comment: Unfortunately that can caused by other rules/code too, try adding [`RewriteLog`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) with a hight enough `RewriteLogLevel` maybe that shed some light on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^index.php?page=9-someting&txt=12$ /page/1/someting#2/other [R=301,L]
```